# Having trouble creating .d.ts files for requirejs module

Tags: typescript

I have a module written using requirejs that I need to get working in Angular 4 .  To understand the process I created a simplified requirejs module and am trying to create a .d.ts file for it However I am having trouble getting the code to compile.

My directory structure looks like

```
.
+--index.html
+--lib
|  +-require
|    +--require.js
|
+--js
|  +-bootstrap.ts
   +-test.js
   +-test
     +-index.d.ts
```

My index.html file looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="js/bootstrap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My bootstrap.js

```
import test from 'test';
add(5,6);
```

My test.js

```
define(function(){
    return {
       add: function(x, y){
           console.log(x + y);
       return x+y;
       }
    };
});
```

My test/index.d.ts

```
export function add(a:number, b:number):number;
```

When I try to compile my bootstrap.ts I get this error

```
bootstrap.ts(2,18): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'test'.
bootstrap.ts(3,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'add'.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 common types of module systems in JavaScript: [AMD](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) (require.js), [Common.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) (used by Node) and [ES6 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) (Still not available, without a flag, in Node.js, but used by TypeScript, even though TypeScript can compile to all 3 module systems).

AMD is asynchronous.. meaning that, when you `require` something, this something, when available, will be provided in a callback.

Example:

```
// AMD
require("x", (x) => { /* x is available here */ })
```

The other 2 are synchronous

```
// CommonJS
var x = require("x")
// x is available here, synchronously (no callback)
```

```
// ES6 Modules
import x from "x"
// x is available here, synchronously (no callback)
```

### After this introduction, now back to your question...

First, there is a problem in your `test.d.ts`.. If `test.js` looks like this:

```
define(function(){
    return {
       add: function(x, y){
           console.log(x + y);
       return x+y;
       }
    };
});
```

Than this module is not returning a function `add`, as you assumed. It is actually returning an object that contains a function add. So, the declaration for this JavaScript file, should be like:

```
declare module "test" {
    const math: {
        add: (a:number, b:number) => number
    }
    export default math
}
```

Notice that I'm completely **ignoring** the `define` function while creating the declaration for `test` here. Why? Because TypeScript *always* use ES6 modules, syntactically, however, when you compile, you can use the `compilerOptions.module` inside your `tsconfig.json` to specify which module system to use.

Now, when you `import` the `test` module, you, again, use ES6 modules and let TypeScript to compile it to AMD, if so you want.

This is how your `bootstrap` file would be:

```
import test from "test"
console.log(test.add(3,4))
```

Again, you got this wrong on your assumption.. If you are importing the module `test`, you cannot call `add` out of nothing. You have to call `test.add`

Now, if you are using `amd` as the TypeScript module system, your **compiled** `bootstrap` file will look like this:

```
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
define(["require", "exports", "test"], function (require, exports, test_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    test_1 = __importDefault(test_1);
    console.log(test_1.default.add(3, 4));
});
```

Comment: I did what you said.  And it does compile but my bootstrap.js looks nothing like yours. my bootstrap.js looks like the following. How does the system know to generate with the dependency of require and exports.  How do I tell tsc to use amd as the typescript module system.

`
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var test_1 = require("./test");
console.log(test_1["default"].add(5, 6));
`

Comment: Add `"module": "amd"` to your `compilerOptions` section in `tsconfig.json`.